# DB2 Rest Server Error during activation of Rest Service

Tags: rest, db2

I'm trying out the IBM Db2 REST Service but I get an Error during the activation of the Rest Service:

I followed the [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.rest.doc/doc/t_download_rest.html)

I have pulled and run db2rest from IBM container registry, started it and could
do a rest call to get a token:

```
curl -k -X POST \
  https://127.0.0.1:50050/v1/auth \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{ 
      "dbParms": {
        "dbHost": "172.17.0.2", 
        "dbName": "TESTDB", 
        "dbPort": 50000,
        "isSSLConnection": false,
        "username": "db2inst1",
        "password": "db2inst1"  
      },
      "expiryTime": "30m" }'
```

Then i wanted to activate the rest capability:

```
curl -k -X POST \
  https://127.0.0.1:50050/v1/metadata/setup \
  -H "authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiMjMxMTAzODgtZmM4OC00NzIwLTg2NTQtNTk5OWM2MjRkMGE0IiwiZXhwIjoxNjAxODI1ODYzLCJpc3MiOiJkYjJpbnN0MSJ9.ZHtsviWUbApw6y-72o5ey7LFf3ys2KEP2jAf7u_36Vq5ASnhKISeIzLXIN5a-OrIasZsQkVjAI5D-9o8Hlilk3mnMVF6XBu5VU7mHZb7k8fnQh75Fk770uCZwlPpgUqcluz6TIcPzUVEmzY5k9uTxWw2-F7Aqi0ruEMV2CBf8iU7KoG1b9apaeqQkY2MI7eSkKiupwkoRCxhF2LMSUUCDZUPMlspN80B5aZ5bUov4o1-j1fS7-_Scm24C4tm6jkwNdNj2CIN7xv6moUjU1oIxzHwbIKLJs6VJARFqLlLLnk9VoINSA1q6X6T9di7tfyqouxPGFagnjtphadNpCfXfg" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{ 
      "schema": "DB2REST"
    }'
```

And i got the Error:

> {"errors":[{"code":"internal_server_error","message":"[Db2 REST] Setup metadata failed.","more_info":"SQLExecute: {42601} [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "@" was found following ".RESTLISTSERVICES(IN".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601\n"}],"trace":null}

I get the same Error with:

```
docker exec db2rest /opt/ibm/dbrest/scripts/db2rest-setup.sh 127.0.0.2 testdb 50000 N DB2REST db2inst1 db2inst1
```

Any Ideas where the Problem could be ?

Comment: May not help you, but I followed IBM's instructions, and the "activating and initializing REST capability" page has the `docker exec ...` instructions which just worked for me (db2_rest-stop ,  db2rest-setup,  db2rest-start) without issue.

Comment: what db2level are you using?

Comment: Is there any particular error in the `/opt/ibm/dbrest/logs/db2rest.log`
 file ?